# Prometheum Exxet: Do any of the Spellcaster item powers grant the item Zeon regen?

Tags: crafting, anima-beyond-fantasy

My GM and I have a definite disagreement over the text of the **Stored Energy** modifier in particular - the text in English is as follows.

> If the object is itself has stored energy (via Zeon Container), the user may use its contained energy to cast the spells it contains.  The transfer rate is 50 Zeon points per Combat Turn.  The item gathers energy *as if it was a spellcaster with Magic Accumulation 50*. (Prometheum Exxet, 28, emphasis mine.)

Is his reading, that the item does not have Zeon regeneration just because it has magic accumulation, correct, or is my reading, that "as a spellcaster" includes ZR, MA, and...such, correct?  Additionally, do any other modifiers seem to give an item ZR of its own?  (I ask because I want to create items that work by themselves, and having no ZR on any of them quite handily precludes that save for reaching to the 'GM fiat' table.)

Comment: Specifically, you can't just make an Infinite Bag as an automatic spell because then you have to *fiddle with it every hour*, as far as I understand the rules there, and you can't just...do that, especially when you're sleeping.

Comment: (the GM has subsequently ruled that I could make an item with No Limits (on the Automatic Spellcaster table) maintain one casting of a spell indefinitely, but I'm still interested in answers here.)

Answer (score 1):

To have the object recover Zeon you would need to give it 2 things. A storage buffer of its own, and the Magical Recharge Modifier.

Given the text of the rest of the modifiers, if the artifact generated 50 zeon of its own entirely seperate of the spellcasting feature, I would think it would come with a comparatively higher cost.

For comparisons sake. Regeneration 50 on an artifact is a level 3 power costing 50 points. This is very substantial. If the stored energy modifier works the way you're suggesting it does, then it makes the regeneration 50 power *entirely* redundant. In fact it would make it borderline pointless. You could make an artifact that casts a level 12-50 spell, *and* regenerates for a fraction of the cost.